# Printing word in Hangman game using nullable char to represent guessed letters

Tags: c#

This is a part of my hangman console application game that I've been trying to make (cut down to show just error) :

```
string TheWord = "dog";
char?[] ThusWord = new char?[TheWord.Length];

// Display the underscores of missing letters. And also the mentioned letters.
foreach (char c in ThusWord)
{
    Console.Write("{0} ", ThusWord[c].HasValue ? ThusWord[c] : "_");
}
```

I want it to display letters/underscores to show the user what has been guessed/ what hasn't. In this general format "_ _ _ a _ _" ('a' being a guessed letter and the underscores representing what hasn't been guessed.

But I'm currently receiving this error that is being thrown at:

```
foreach (char c in ThusWord)
```

With the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll 
>      Additional information: Nullable object must have a value.

I'm guessing it's probably something to do with the fact that I'm using a char array.

Comment: Have you tried using `if (ThusWord[c] != NULL)` instead of `if (ThusWord[c].HasValue)`

Comment: @Armin Just tried that and it returned the same error.

Comment: For future questions please provide [MCVE] and avoid all sort of "thank you"/"new here", signatures and long history of problems. See my edit that shows version that is close to minimal. Note that edit significantly changing the code is not really welcome on SO and you are free to roll it back.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I agree with you. But I'm going to continue to say thank you to those that go out of their way to help me.

Comment: @TravisS. I would recommend reading results of following search https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluff+remove before you finalize your decision about "thank you" text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't directly cast `char?` to `char` (it may be null and therefor you get exception). Also `ThusWord[c]` is wrong. `c` is the char itself. You use indexer `[int]` to get the char at specified position of string.

```
foreach (char? c in ThusWord)
{
   if (c.HasValue)
   {
       Console.Write(c + " ");
   }
   else
   {
       Console.Write("_ ");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Looks like I've gotten one step closer. But now in my IDE it says that: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'char?' to 'int'.`
On the lines: `if (ThusWord[c].HasValue)` and `Console.Write(ThusWord[c] + " ");`

Comment: Ah, just refreshed page.
Thank you very much! I'll mark your answer as correct when the timer is up. :)

Comment: You *can* cast `char?` to `char`, only that you get an exception if it happens to be null. You might do this to assert the fact that you "know" that it is not null, for example. (And then if you're wrong, indicating a programming error, then your program explodes (which is what you want to happen when you've identified a programming error).)